# C++ Passing member function reference from a class instance to another class instance

Tags: c++, callback

I'm very new to C++ and I'm struggling on a project where I need to transmit a reference to a callback method between to different class instances. I know that this subject is a pretty common issue for C++ beginners. I understand that member function pointers are different from the "standard" function ones, but I cannot find any post that adresses my specific problem (but may be it is because, given my lack of experience with C++ I don't understand the provided answers).

The system I try to develop is based on :

- A **ControllerManager** class (which is a Singleton)
- A **Controller** base class
- Some specific Controller classes (**FanController**, **LighController**, etc) which inherits from the Controller class

What I would like to do is from let say a **FanController** instance to call an **addCallback** method of the **ControllerManager** class. This method would take as a parameter a pointer to any public method of the FanController so that the ControllerManager could made a callback to this method later (I must specify that the ControllerManager include the definition of the Controller class but doesn't know anything about the FanController class)

So far I didn't found any working solution, the only thing I managed to get is a very poor workaround (for simplicity, only relevant methods are indicated) :

```
class Controller {

public:
    virtual void callback();
};


class FanController:Controller {

public:
    virtual void callback();
};


class ControllerManager
{
private:
    static ControllerManager *_instance;
    Controller *_controller;

public:

    void addCallback(Controller * controller)
    {
        _controller = controller;
    }

    static void periodicCallback()
    {
       _instance->_controller->callback();
    }
};
```

At runtime the FanController instance provides a reference of herself to the ControllerManager singleton :

```
ControllerManager::getInstance()->addController(this);
```

and the ControllerManager can make a call to the callback method of the FanController instance:

```
 _instance->_controller->callback();
```

This workaround is very limited since it allows only calls to methods declared by the parent **Controller** class.

What I would to implement is a system that allows the specifics controllers to provide references of their member methods (which doesn't exist in the Controller class) to the ControllerManager so that it can make calls to those methods.

If someone can help me I thanks him/her in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The modern way of tackling this is to squirrel away the method's binding in a lambda.

```
#include <functional>
#include <vector>


class Controller {
  std::vector<std::function<void()>> callbacks_;

public: 
  void addCallback(std::function<void()> cb) {
      callbacks_.push_back(std::move(cb));
  }

  void periodicCallback() {
     for(const auto& cb : callbacks_) {
       cb();
     }
  }
};


class Fan {
public:
  void whatever() {}

  void register_in_controller(Controller* tgt) {
    tgt->addCallback([this]{whatever();});
  }
};
```

Comment: Hello Frank, Thank you for your answer. I should have specified that this code is executed on an ESP32 microcontroler (Arduino framework) and it seems that st::function is not available on this platform.

Comment: Frank, sorry, I responded too quickly. Id do have access to <functional> and your solution works like a charm. Thank you very much for your answer !